# moving sql server 2012 mdf &ldf but my hdd full

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, mdf, ldf

currently  my server c drive almost all full only left 20Gb ,and i have a big database table with 11 millions records  of binary images .
now i need to move my mdf and ldf files to another hard drive to empty the c drive and keep the performance of server fine please can u advice me with the correct way
my sql.server version is 2012 andwindows version 2012 data center

i tried to move or backup my big table using sql delta software, but the c drive free space not enough becasue of log file which created  by sql delta software

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Detach database, move mdf/ldf files, the attach the database.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396